# JUnit testing with Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, junit

Is it possible to specify the maven profile when running JUnit tests from Eclipse?

I tried lookin at the JUnit menu from Eclipse however no option or that. I think this can only be achieved by running tests as maven build.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you must install the m2e plugin (Maven Integration for Eclipse).
Then right click on the project and choose Properties -> Maven.
There you can activate maven profiles.

Note: Of course this enables the maven profiles for the project and not only for JUnit tests. Hope this helps anyway.

[image]